# $RYSNC_PASSWORD not being read/responded-to correctly (Snow Leopard)

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, bash, rsync

Ignoring the security issues, I have the following script that synchronizes my music library from my MacBook Pro (running Snow Leopard) to the file store (CentOS 4) on my network:

```
rsync -rav --progress --partial -e "ssh" ~/Music/iTunes/* user@scramasax:~/music/iTunes-scissor:~
```

When I try to use either a password provided on the command-line (), in a password file (`--password-file`), or in the environment variable `RSYNC_PASSWORD`, the login still goes interactive, requiring me to type my password again.

I will be moving to pre-shared keys on my network, but in situations where that is not possible, such as `rsync`'ing files to a webserver, being able to successfully embed the password in the script would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note what these sections from [`man rsync`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) have to say about `ssh`. You'll probably have to set up keyfiles.

> --password-file
>                 This option allows you to provide  a  password  in  a  file  for
>                 accessing an rsync daemon.  The file must not be world readable.
>                 It should contain just the password as a single line.

```
          This option does not supply a password to a remote shell  trans‐
          port  such  as  ssh; to learn how to do that, consult the remote
          shell's documentation.  When accessing an rsync daemon  using  a
          remote  shell  as  the  transport,  this  option only comes into
          effect after the remote shell finishes its authentication  (i.e.
          if  you  have  also  specified a password in the daemon's config
          file).
```

> RSYNC_PASSWORD
>                 Setting  RSYNC_PASSWORD  to  the required password allows you to
>                 run authenticated rsync connections to an rsync  daemon  without
>                 user  intervention. Note that this does not supply a password to
>                 a remote shell transport such as ssh; to learn how to  do  that,
>                 consult the remote shell's documentation.

Comment: that could explain it

Comment: yes - that's it. I just didn't read far enough in the man pages. Thanks!